# Performance boost needed - app users fanpage likes check

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-like

I have performance issues with my facebook app.

I need to check, if app users friends like an fanpage. But problem is: time.

One query to graph /fanpage_id/members/userId needs ~200ms (my test user have 4 friends, time was 977ms). Customer want at last one check per 24hours(app cache remove event on global.asax works well) for all users BUT.. lets say 500 users and every user have 500 friends * 200ms .. its a lot of time and queries to facebook graph.

Any ideas how improve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [batch requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)?

Comment: Im now checking it. I ll post results soon.

Comment: Performance increased. I only had to split user friends into 20 per pack. (batch request 20 queries limit).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reduce the time by using the ?fields=  &fields= parameter and only requesting the id's of friends and id's of like objects.

- *when you request friends **/me/friends?fields=id***

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did

**foreach id:**

- *when you request likes **/id/likes?fields=id***

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes%3Ffields%3Did

Comment: I havn't noticed bigger difference in speed with ?fields=id. Maybe I need test it more.